# Convergence of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness, infinite-product

I'm looking at some notes from my previous complex variables course and I need help verifying some things about the convergence of
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)
$$
on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. My professor shows its convergence by using the property of infinite products which states that $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log(1-a_n)$ converges, given $a_n\neq 1$ for each $n$. I have a few issues I would like to work out with this:

1. **$\mathbf{\frac{z^2}{n^2}=1}$ when $\mathbf{z=\pm n}$, which one would think makes the property inapplicable**.

   I believe I have maneuvered around this hurdle because if $z$
   belongs to an arbitrary compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, then
   $\frac{z^2}{n^2}=1$ for only finitely many $n$, there exists an
   $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{z^2}{n^2}\neq 1$ for all $n\geq
   N$, and it suffices to check convergence of
   $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$. The
   only thing that concerns me is that this point wasn't mentioned in
   the notes whatsoever.
2. **Convergence $\mathbf{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)}$ is shown by noticing $\mathbf{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right|}$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbf{\mathbb{C}}$** (through the Weierstrass M-test, for example).

   I've thought this through but I don't see it at all. I was thinking
   it might be because $\log\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$,
   could be thought of as a function of $\frac{z^2}{n^2}$, but this
   cannot hold always since $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ is a function of
   $\frac{1}{n^2}$ but the sum of these terms clearly does not
   converge.

Any help on these points is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first question: If $z=\pm n$ then $1-\tfrac{z^2}{n^2}=0$, so the entire product equals $0$. To see that the product converges we remove this term from the product, and the argument below serves just as well to show that the product converges.

Your second question does require some effort. I don't see how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\tfrac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$ converges, but I'm able to prove the product converges uniformly on compact sets using a lovely little lemma on infinite products. I've chopped the proof up into three parts:

$$\ $$

**1. Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\tfrac{z^2}{n^2}\right|$ on compact subsets of $\Bbb{C}$**

Let $B\subset\Bbb{C}$ compact and $M\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $|z|\leq M$ holds for all $z\in B$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{n^2}$ can be seen to converge, say to $L$,${}^{\dagger}$ by noting that it is strictly positive and increasing, and satisfies
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}<1+\sum_{n=2}^k\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1+\sum_{n=2}^k\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=2-\frac{1}{k},$$
for all $k\geq1$. It follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\tfrac{z^2}{n^2}\right|$ converges uniformly to $|z|^2L$ on $B$, as for all $z\in B$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^k\left|\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right|-|z|^2L\right|=|z|^2\left|\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}-L\right|\leq M^2\cdot\left|\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}-L\right|.$$
This indeed means the series converges uniformly, because the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges to $L$.

$$\ $$

**2. An often useful lemma on infinite products**

**Lemma:** *If a sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|1-\alpha_n|\leq\frac{1}{2}$, then for all $m\geq1$ we have*
$$\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|\leq2\sum_{n=1}^m|1-\alpha_n|.$$

*Proof:* We proceed by induction. The base case $m=1$ is obvious, so suppose the inequality holds for some $m\geq1$. From the induction hypothesis we get 
\begin{align}
\left|\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|\leq1+\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|\leq1+2\sum_{n=1}^m|1-\alpha_n|\leq2.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Then it is a matter of some clever rewriting to see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^{m+1}\alpha_n\right|
   &=&\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n
     +\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n
     -\prod_{n=1}^{m+1}\alpha_n\right|\\
&\leq&\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|
     +\left|\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|
 \cdot\left|1-\alpha_{m+1}\right|\\
&\leq&2\sum_{n=1}^m\left|1-\alpha_n\right|+2\left|1-\alpha_{m+1}\right|
     =2\sum_{n=1}^{m+1}\left|1-\alpha_n\right|.\tag*{$\Box$}
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that this shows in particular that $\left|1-\prod_{n=1}^m\alpha_n\right|\leq1$ holds for all $m\geq1$.

$$\ $$

**3. Actually showing that the product converges**

Now there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left|\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ holds for all $z\in B$; simply take $N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{2M^2}.$$
Hence we can apply the lemma to the sequence $(p_n(z))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by $p_n(z):=1-\tfrac{z^2}{(N+n)^2}$, because
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|1-p_n(z)|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{z^2}{(N+n)^2}\right|=\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}.$$
Note that if $z=\pm k$ then $N>|k|$, so $p_n(z)$ is nonzero for all $n\geq1$. Setting $P_m(z):=\prod_{n=1}^mp_n(z)$ we can show the sequence $(P_m(z))_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly on $B$. The lemma together with inequality (1) shows that for integers $a>b\geq1$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|P_a(z)-P_b(z)\right|
   &=&\left|\prod_{n=1}^bp_n(z)\right|
 \cdot\left|1-\prod_{n=b+1}^ap_n(z)\right|\\
   &<&2\cdot2\sum_{n=b+1}^a|1-p_n(z)|
     =4\sum_{n=b+1}^a\left|\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right|\\
&\leq&4M^2\sum_{n=b+1}^a\frac{1}{n^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $|P_a(z)-P_b(z)|\ \rightarrow\ 0$ as $a,b\ \rightarrow\ \infty$, so $(P_m(z))_{m=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly on $B$, to
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}P_m(z)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\prod_{n=N+1}^{N+m}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)=\prod_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right).$$
It follows immediately that we also have uniform convergence on $B$ for the product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^N\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)\cdot\prod_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right).$$

$$\ $$

---

$\dagger$ In fact the series can be shown to converge to $L=\tfrac{\pi^2}{6}$, this is the  [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

---

For completeness sake I include my original answer below. It only shows convergence on the disk $|z|<(2\pi^2)^{-1}$, but it also shows a few interesting connections.

Using the power series of $\operatorname{Log}(1-x)$ we find that

$$\operatorname{Log}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\tfrac{z^2}{n^2}\right)^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{kn^{2k}},$$

so interchanging the order of summation (why is this allowed?) yields
  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{Log}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}},$$
where now the inner sum (over $n$) is an instance of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), which for the positive even integers just so happens to converge to
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k}}=\zeta(2k)=(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!},$$
where $B_m$ is a [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Hence we can simplify the above to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{k}\cdot(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_{2k}}{2(2k)!}\frac{(-2\pi^2z^2)^k}{k}.$$
Now it suffice to note that $0<B_{2k}<2(2k)!$ for sufficiently large $k$, which can be seen using Stirling's approximations for $B_{2k}$ and $(2k)!$. Now the series above converges whenever the series
$$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2\pi^2z^2)^k}{k}=\operatorname{Log}(1+2\pi^2z^2),$$
converges, which is the case for $|z|<(2\pi^2)^{-1}$ as can be seen by the ratio test, for example.

Comment: just curious ... what is the radius of convergence of the series $-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-2\pi^2z^2)^k}{k}$?  If $z=1$, does that series converge to $\log (1+2\pi^2)$ for example?

Comment: The series converge on all of $\Bbb{C}$ except the $z\in\Bbb{C}$ for which we get $\log(0)$, so except for
$$z=\pm(\pi\sqrt{2})^{-1}i.$$
So yes, if $z=1$ it converges to $\log(1+2\pi^2)$.

Comment: So, it is your belief that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2\pi^2)^k}{k}$ converges even though the terms of the series do not tend to zero and in fact are unbounded?  What test would one use to show that?

Comment: @Dr. MV I think there's a typo there. And it is currently 03:39 AM here, so I'll look at what i wrote again tomorrow.

Comment: No worry.  Rest up.  I just got out of surgery a few hours ago.

Comment: The disk of converges of that series is (at most) $|z|<(2\pi^{-2})^{-1}$, as we certainly cannot have convergence for $\log(0)$. So your question about $z=1$ is a good one; it shows that my answer leaves a big part of the problem open. I will revise my answer.

Comment: We don't say that a product converges whenever it contains a factor $0$. We say that a product containing zero factors converges when a) it contains only finitely many zero factors, and b) the product obtained by removing the zero factors converges [and convergence of a product of nonzero factors means the limit is not $0$].

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the clarification! All these sequences and their converence are things pretty far outside my field (I haven't deal with such things since basic undergraduate calculus, years ago), so I went with the naïve idea that a product converges whenever it contains a factor $0$. But if I'm not mistaken the exact same argument will hold if $z=n$. I'll double-check and edit soon.

Comment: Everything is fine with convergence in this example. We say that a product $\prod(1+ a_n)$ converges absolutely if $\prod(+\lvert a_n\rvert)$ converges. Since for $\lvert u\rvert\leqslant\frac{1}{3}$ we have $$\frac{3}{4}\lvert u\rvert\leqslant\lvert \operatorname{Log} (1+u)\rvert \leqslant \frac{3}{2}\lvert u\rvert,$$ we see that a product $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum \operatorname{Log} (1+a_n)$ [here the $n$ with $a_n = -1$ must be omitted] converges absolutely if and only if $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert < +\infty$. Since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} < +\infty$, it's fine here.